# Simple regex addition to my existing code

Tags: php

```
$options = '<select name="extra2"  id="extra2" class="select_smaller">
    <option value="Algema">Algema</option>
    <option value="Barkas">Barkas</option>
.
.
.
</select>';
```

**and this is my code**

```
/**
 * Return HTML of select field with one option selected, built based
 * on the list of options provided
 * @param mixed $options array of options or HTML of select form field
 * @return string HTML of the select field
 */
function makeSelect($name, $options) {
if (is_string($options)) {
    // assuming the options string given is HTML of select field
    $regex = '/<option value=\"([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\"\>/';
    $count = preg_match_all($regex, $options, $matches);
    if ($count) {
        $options = $matches[1];
    } else {
        $options = array();
    }
}

foreach ($options as &$option) {
    $selected = isset($_GET[$name]) && $_GET[$name] == $option;
    $option = sprintf('<option value="%1$s"%2$s>%1$s</option>',
                      htmlspecialchars($option),
                      $selected ? ' selected="selected"' : null);
}

return sprintf('<select name="%1$s" id="%1$s" class="select">%2$s</select>',
               htmlspecialchars($name),
               join($options));
}

echo makeSelect('extra2', $options);
```

How can I get the name of the select list using a regex instead of manually writing it (extra2) ?

Comment: Can you be a little clearer on what you are trying to accomplish? It seems to me that you want to parse a segment of HTML using regex to capture the names of the available options in the select-input? Why do you have an HTML-string inside PHP to begin with? Were do you get that HTML from?

Comment: I have like 500 forms with 2-3 dropdownlists in each of them. I can't edit them one by one, so this code will help me to produce and show the correct result for my case where I want the option value to be selected based on the url data. The code is working fine, except of the fact that I need to manually add the name on each of them. When I have a solution I will replace all the forms with a mass search and replace program.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question. Where does the content of the $options variable come from? Did you make that string yourself, or did you get it from somewhere else?

Comment: I made that string from my self. The code is working correctly but I don't want to set the dropdown list name for every form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<?php
function selectOption($htmlSelect, array $data = array()) {
    $result = $htmlSelect;

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    if ($dom->loadXml($htmlSelect)) {
        $selectName = $dom->documentElement->getAttribute('name');
        if (isset($data[$selectName])) {
            $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

            $optionNodeList = $xpath->query('//option[@value="' . $data[$selectName] . '"]');
            if ($optionNodeList->length == 1) {
                $optionNodeList->item(0)->setAttribute('selected', 'selected');

                $result = $dom->saveXml($dom->documentElement, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$htmlSelect = '<select name="extra2" id="extra2" class="select_smaller">
    <option value="Algema">Algema</option>
    <option value="Barkas">Barkas</option>
</select>';

echo selectOption(
    $htmlSelect,
    array('extra2' => 'Barkas') // could be $_GET, $_POST or something else
));
```

I guess you'll have to add some error checking here and there.

Comment: Thank you but not what I am looking for. I need to edit the code above.

Comment: Of course, this is no replacement for your code, but you could add it, or something like this, at the appropiate place. As your question is rather vague, I couldn't give a better example.

Comment: Do you always have this kind of string and only want to "select" the correct option, or do you actually use the function in the way the code comment suggests?

Comment: All of my dropdown lists have the same structure but different names and yes it does only select the right one.

Comment: Thanks for this, I got this on page source `<select class="select_smaller" id="extra2" name="extra2">
    <option value="Algema">Algema</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="Barkas">Barkas</option>
</select>`

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You parse the HTML using http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make that string to begin with. Work on the data you have, before concatenating to a string.

Most likely, you should not need to make a huge string after working on the data either. Can't you run a loop and echo the HTML out, putting in the variables were needed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure of $option structure, you can do:

```
function makeSelect($name, $options) {
    if (is_string($options)) {
        preg_match('/<select name="(.+?)"/', $options, $match);
        $name = $match[1];
        ...
```

You could also build $options to contains the nameof the select this way:

```
$options = array(
    'name'   => 'The name',
    'options => ...
);
```